# Final interview tomorrow, the bank is now being accused of money laundering

Tags: interviewing

I've been interviewing with a bank now for a few weeks. Tomorrow is the final interview, basically either an offer or good bye.

Anyway, two days ago, several sources claimed that the bank have been laundering money for a couple of years. This has led to an 25 % decrease in the company stock in recent days.

The manager I'm interviewing with has to my knowledge nothing to do with this. The team that he is responsible for is not part of the group who is being accused, they are just a part of the company.

My question is, should I bring this up? Should I act as if nothing has happend?

Comment: are these trustworthy sources or are they rumors?

Comment: @jesse public service is the on who started the claim and they have handed over their proof. This led to several other independent news stations to jump on the train. The bank is now under investigation by the finance department.

Comment: every7 bank is accused of "money laundering" - it's what banks do.  Ignore it.   BTW you are not wise to post this on here .. it will probably get back  :O

Comment: @JoeStrazzere well, the job is to analyze different assets. Seems natural to be following the company stock. And to show that you follow the market. I.e a question like "Ive noticed that your stock has decrease with x % last two days, how does a sudden drastic decrease like that change your way of analyzing assets and the products which you offer ln the market?"  So my gain would be showing interest in the market. Learn how they operate during pressure and under market changes which is unpredictable.

Comment: @johny.doe telling me that would translate as, "Ive noticed that your stock has decrease with x % last two days, _because of the laundering money_ ....", pretty much you'll remember them something that's being doing wrong, don't do that on interview, do it when you're already inside

Comment: @Fattie - "every7 bank is accused of "money laundering" - it's what banks do." huh? That makes no sense. Very few financial institutions are accused of money laundering, and it's clearly *not* what they "do."

Comment: ?  the biggest one just had to pay a fine of 1.5 billion (with a b) in the latest money-laundering show trial.  Banks (large banks) exist for the purpose of laundering money for the powerful.

Comment: It would be a bit like asking "I'm thinking of working for a government.  But I've heard news stories about government waste ..."   Or it would be like asking "I'm thinking of working for Playboy. But I've heard that industry involves pornography..."  You know!

Answer (score 14):

> Should I bring this up?

No.

> Should I act as if nothing has happened?

Yes.

Only exception may be if you are interviewing for a PR related position. Even in this case you need to be very careful when choosing words and avoid being judgemental.

You can cancel the interview if you really don't see yourself willing to work for this company because of the bad press. **But as long as you are still attending the interview, stay professional and leave unrelated distraction out of it.**

You can consider seriously about if this is going to be a problem for you (to really work for this company) after you have an offer. Before that, you treat it as any other interview you'd take, bad press about the company is not yet your concern.

Comment: Suggestion for a Caveat: There *are* positions for which "maintains constant situational awareness of the people and organizations around them" could be considered a vital job skill, and in those, it might be appropriate to reference the matter delicately.  Most jobs that a bank might offer you aren't on that list.

Comment: It depends on the type of position, for example if you were interviewing for the social media manager position, or other types of public relations, these types of issues would be something you would really want to discuss.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes you are right, it might be something on topic if OP is interviewing a PR related position, I will edit the exception in.

Answer (score 5):

You're evaluating whether you want to work there, and it appears the stock drop is making you question that.  You certainly don't want to take a job and immediately face the possibility of layoffs.

So yes, it is reasonable to bring it up.  But since it is still in the allegations stages, you don't KNOW it is true, and your discussion needs to make that clear.

> The allegations that have been in the news lately - do you think those will have any effect on this department?

And then listen.

The hiring manager should be thinking of this too - are you getting the sense they are leveling with you or trying to deflect and change the subject?  If they acknowledge this does cause them concern, but that this shouldn't be an issue because of /reasons/, then that is a lot better then if they get offended that you even ask.  If they say "no, it won't be an issue" and then change the subject, then... maybe it won't be an issue, and maybe it will but they don't want to tell you - you have no way of knowing.  In other words, how they respond *might* give you some insight.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, should I bring this up?

Only if different possible answers lead to different actions on your side. That is, they there is an answer X which make you decide not to work for them, while an answer Y makes you want to continue the process.

But how likely is such a situation? It would not only require the person having enough knowledge about the alledged money laundring, said person must also be allowed to share that knowledge with you.

That seems unlikely. Beside, are there really different answers which would make you act differently?

So, you probably should not bring this up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the place you will be working for. Day in and day out you will be interacting with these people and you will be an employee of this company. You working for this company will be on your resume. Moreover it will be on your conscience.

So with any job, ask yourself: **Do the company's goals and morals line up with yours?** Don't work for a company you hate, don't trust, or don't enjoy their products. It won't be the job you are best fit for. So if this is concerning to you, and the sources of information seem reputable, **I would ask**. You either avoid a company who may have legal trouble in the future if its true (which can effect your employment/difficult of job), get a better understanding of the company's response during rocky times, or solidify your enjoyment of how the company does business.

This *could* jeopardize your employment there if asked in the wrong way. Politely ask them about the situation and ask for their side of the story - do not accuse. Heck! You'll get a side of the story most news sources won't by doing so. If they respond with a nasty response after you've asked *nicely* - congratulations! I see this as avoiding a company who is unkind to those who question the status quo. If they respond nicely with a reasonable answer, you can rest assured.

There are plenty of other banking jobs! Don't trap yourself into the corner by thinking this may be the only one.